# How to get key value from object inside array JSON using PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, foreach, powershell-4.0

I am trying to get the key value from object inside JSON array, please also suggest if I need to change my RuleId key structure, below is the output I want

```
rule = 1300
rulevalue = false
    
rule = 1304
rulevalue = true
```

**JSON file**

```
{
    "Rule": [{
        "MPName": "ManagementPackProject",
        "Request": "Apply",
        "Category": "Rule",
        "RuleId": {
            "1300": "false",
            "1304": "true"
        }
    }]
}
```

**PowerShell**

```
$Content = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\temp\Rule.json" | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction Stop
$Content = $Content.Rule | Where-Object { $_.Request -eq "Apply" }

foreach($item in $Content.RuleId)
{
    rule = $item.key
    rulevalue = $item.value
    
    process...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you after something like this?

```
$JSON = @'
    {
        "Rule": [{
            "MPName": "ManagementPackProject",
            "Request": "Apply",
            "Category": "Rule",
            "RuleId": {
                "1300": "false",
                "1304": "true"
            }
        }]
    }
'@

$Content = $JSON | ConvertFrom-Json
$Content = $Content.Rule | Where-Object Request -eq 'Apply'

$Output = foreach( $Rule in $Content.RuleId.psobject.Properties ) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Rule = $Rule.Name
        RuleValue = $Rule.Value
    }
}
$Output | Format-List
```

Output:

```
Rule      : 1300
RuleValue : false

Rule      : 1304
RuleValue : true
```

Comment: Hi @PMental just 1 thing how to count how many properties there `$Content.RuleId.psobject.Properties.Length` not working

Comment: Force it into an array like this `@($Content.RuleId.psobject.Properties).Length`

Comment: @PMental Is there a way to collect and assign 'Rule' and 'RuleValue' values to a variable and later use it ? I found your answer useful but it is only printing output.

Comment: @user1557960 That's already there in the script, they're all stored in the $Output variable.